# how to find the most frequent character in each postion of multiple strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I have a list of words with different length.
I want to find the most frequent character in each position of all words. what is the efficient way to do that and prevent the Error `index out of range` in different length strings?
for example:

```
alist = ['fowey', 'tynemouth', 'unfortunates', 'patroness', 'puttying', 'presumptuousness', 'lustrous', 'gloxinia']
```

The most frequent character in each position of all words (`0 to len(max(alist, key=len))`) is equal to: `poternusakesness`

```
for p in range (len(max(words, key=len))):
```

and what about, if two characters have the same frequenct, the first character (based on alphabet) be selected as the most frequent character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from collections import Counter

alist = [
    "fowey",
    "tynemouth",
    "unfortunates",
    "patroness",
    "puttying",
    "presumptuousness",
    "lustrous",
    "gloxinia",
]

for i in (
    (w[idx] if idx < len(w) else None for w in alist)
    for idx in range(len(max(alist, key=len)))
):
    print(
        min(
            Counter(ch for ch in i if ch is not None).items(),
            key=lambda k: (-k[1], k[0]),
        )[0]
    )
```

Prints:

```
p
u
t
e
r
n
u
s
a
o
e
s
n
e
s
s
```

---

EDIT: Withour `collections.Counter`:

```py
alist = [
    "fowey",
    "tynemouth",
    "unfortunates",
    "patroness",
    "puttying",
    "presumptuousness",
    "lustrous",
    "gloxinia",
]


for i in (
    (w[idx] if idx < len(w) else None for w in alist)
    for idx in range(len(max(alist, key=len)))
):
    cnt = {}
    for ch in i:
        if ch is not None:
            cnt[ch] = cnt.get(ch, 0) + 1

    print(
        min(
            cnt.items(),
            key=lambda k: (-k[1], k[0]),
        )[0]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please desribe that a bit to make that clear?

Comment: @danial First I'm searching for max-length word, then I'm iterating from 0 to maxlen-1 and get character at that index for each word (or `None` if the index is out of bounds). Then I'm constructing `collections.Counter` (from non-`None` values) and search for most common character using `max()`

Comment: Thanks for your time and explaining. Is that possible to doing that without collections library and Counter module?